# SQL server default instance with a different port

Tags: sql-server, sql-default-instance

One of our clients have SQL server default instance running on a non-default port. So, the connection string from our application should be servername,1234.

They don't want to create aliases on the MS SQL server.

Is there any different way our application can connect to it?

It is a default instance, so can I use servername\MSSQLServer

Thank you!

Comment: if it is default instance, you can just give the Servername.You dont need "servername\MSSQLServer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Browser does not support connecting to a default instance with

```
servername\MSSQLServer
```

> They don't want to create aliases on the MS SQL server.

That wouldn't help anyway.  Aliases are created on the client computer, not the SQL Server.

See [Create or Delete a Server Alias for Use by a Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client)